# how to get text from Ngx data table using Xpath selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, ngx-datatable

```
WebElement NumberofRecord = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tableContent\"]/div[2]/span/a"));
NumberofRecord.getText();               

System.out.println(NumberofRecord);
```

trying to get the text but returning URL

Result: xpath: //*[@id="tableContent"]/div[2]/span/a]

```
Expected Output: All 18418 Messages in Table are selected. Clear selection(this need to be displayed)
```

[image]

Comment: Post the relevant html?

Comment: Do you mean the anchor tag having text value `18418` or you have `18418` numbers of anchor tag inside table?

Comment: @KunduK i have added image please check

Comment: <div _ngcontent-C11 class="select-option">
<span _ngcontenet-c11 xpath="1"> == $0  "All 1810 messages in Table are selected. "
<a _ngcontenet-c11>Clear Selection</a>
</span>
</div>

Note: message number very all the time its depend on number of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `visibilityOfElementLocated`() and then get the text value.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='tableContent']/div[2]/span/a"))); 
WebElement NumberofRecord = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tableContent']/div[2]/span/a"));
System.out.println(NumberofRecord.getText());
```